# Add ascending index to each document using mongodb Java driver 3.6+

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to add the field named as `index` with [ascending value](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/tutorials/indexes/) to each document like:

```
    _id:454dfddf34
    field:"..."
    field:"..."
    field:"..."
    index:1

    _id:5bcf47c460
    field:"..."
    field:"..."
    field:"..."
    index:2

     _id:433jkdc46
    field:"..."
    field:"..."
    field:"..."
    index:3
```

And so on.

So, I'm writing the code for adding:

```
Document found = database.getCollection("name").find(new Document("field", "...")
                .append("field", "...")
                .append("field", "...")
                .append("field", "...")).first();

        if (found == null) {
            collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("index"));
            collection.insertOne(new Document("field", "...")
                    .append("field", "...")
                    .append("field", "...")
                    .append("field", "...")
                    .append("index", 1));
        }
```

But the result is:

```
_id:454dfddf34
field:"..."
field:"..."
field:"..."
index:1

_id:5bcf47c460
field:"..."
field:"..."
field:"..."
index:1

 _id:433jkdc46
field:"..."
field:"..."
field:"..."
index:1
```

Why it happens? Correct me, please.

Comment: How quickly do you write your documents? Do you wait to acknowledge the writes (look at driver settings)?

Comment: @9000, I'm writing documents one by one, during 1 minute. I want to get each document that have additional field with ascending value, as you can see my example. But in my case, all documents have instead of different values, just one.

Comment: This means that `found` is always null. With several documents already stored, I'd manually verify the condition for finding a previous document. and made sure it indeed works. MongoDB has a decent REPL.